# Subjunctive mood in a 3rd conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

> If you had been my child, I would have *demanded* that such an irresponsible teacher **be** fired.

It is the subjunctive mood, I suppose. Why every verb in the sentence in the *past*, but **be** is in the *present*?

Comment: This is a "mandative subjunctive", discussed here: ["It was recommended that" + verb in present tense](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/it-was-recommended-that-verb-in-present-tense).

Comment: I'm closevoting as a Dup of that earlier question, but would just point out that **be** here isn't really "present tense" at all - it's just a "bare infinitive". In this exact context, a "tensed" version of the verb can't be used, but in similar constructions it's (informally, at least) possible. *"If he hits my child, I will demand that such an aggressive teacher **is** fired"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subjunctive tenses are a little more abstract with respect to time than indicative ones are.  This is a good overview of usage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

With the verb *to be*, past tense implies a condition known not to be the case, whereas present tense doesn't imply that knowledge.  For example:

> If Abraham Lincoln were alive today, he probably wouldn't be able to run for president.
>
> Be he alive or be he dead, I'll grind his bones to make my bread.